# Roles and system roles greyed out in SQL Server 2008R2 Management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unable to add new roles, custom reports, or open properties due to the greying out of options in roles and system roles when Right clicking these in Object Explorer of SQL Server Reporting Services Management Studio. I am not sure why, does anyone have an answer, please help. It works fine originally until I encountered issues with permission when performing the Technet's tutorial 'Creating a new report from Getting started': the connection to ProductSales can't be created due my insufficient permission as local administrator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is your sql server management studio running on admin login?? if not right click on it and run as admin.

Comment: Thanks @czar41, it now works. I never know that I can run as admin in SQL Server Management studio too as I always open the normal way. Next time I will try this every time I encounter permission issues.